How to fit a variable number of react-bootstrap accordions to a page correctly
I am trying to make a webpage with react-bootstrap and I made a top bar. Under the top bar I am trying to add some accordions. The number of the accordions will be dynamic because I will get data from server. When I add, let's say 8 accordions, they tend to expand the row where they are put as per the overflow property of the row. The problem with this expansion is that it happens vertically equally on top and on bottom, shifting the first accordions to the top and under the top bar. I need a way to make expand the row vertically bottom only.
Here is the Homepage:
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {useState} from "react";
import NavigationBar from "./NavigationBar.jsx";
import GameCard from "./GameCard.jsx";
import {Row} from "react-bootstrap";
import {Container} from "react-bootstrap/";

function Homepage(props) {
    const [user] = useState(props.user);

    return(
        <>
            <NavigationBar
                user={user}
                logout={props.logout}
            />
            <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    <GameCard round={1}/>
                    <GameCard round={2}/>
                    <GameCard round={3}/>
                    <GameCard round={1}/>
                    <GameCard round={2}/>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    );
}

Homepage.propTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default Homepage;

It starts with the navigation bar which is this function:
import {Button, Container, Image, Navbar} from "react-bootstrap";
import logoutIcon from "../assets/logout.png";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function NavigationBar(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar expand={"lg"} className="bg-dark rounded-bottom-5" fixed={"top"}>
                <Container fluid>
                    <Navbar.Brand to='/homepage'>
                        <h2 className="mx-3 text-light">What do you meme?</h2>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                    <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <i className="bi bi-person-circle text-white h3"></i>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Text className="text-white">
                            <h5>{props.user.username}</h5>
                        </Navbar.Text>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <Button
                            variant="transparent"
                            onClick={props.logout}
                        >
                            <Image className="mx-1" src={logoutIcon} width={90} height={70} rounded/>
                        </Button>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </>
    );
}

NavigationBar.propTypes = {
    logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default NavigationBar;

Another "problem" I noticed is that in Homepage when I try to add elements under the NavigationBar, they are centered vertically and horizontally. Here is the single accordion function:
import {Container} from "react-bootstrap/";
import {Accordion, Col, Image} from "react-bootstrap";
import logo from "../assets/image.jpg";

function GameCard() {
    return (
        <Col>
            <Container className="mb-4 rounded-3 bg-light fixed-width-accordion">
                <h3 className="text-primary pt-3">Game</h3>
                <Accordion>
                    <Accordion.Item eventKey="0" className="pb-2">
                        <Accordion.Header>Round 1</Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Body>
                            <Image src={logo} alt={"Round 1"} width={200} height={200}/>
                        </Accordion.Body>
                    </Accordion.Item>
                    <Accordion.Item eventKey="1" className="pb-2">
                        <Accordion.Header>Round 2</Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Body>
                            <Image src={"../assets/loginMeme.jpg"} alt={"Round 2"} width={200} height={200}/>
                        </Accordion.Body>
                    </Accordion.Item>
                    <Accordion.Item eventKey="2" className="pb-2 mb-2">
                        <Accordion.Header>Round 3</Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Body>
                            <Image src="../assets/loginMeme.jpg" alt={"Round 3"} width={200} height={200}/>
                        </Accordion.Body>
                    </Accordion.Item>
                </Accordion>
            </Container>
        </Col>
    );
}

export default GameCard;

I tried changing flex direction of the row with css but it's not working.
